# `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys ` when trying to access Youtube Data Api v3

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm following the Modern Redux With React tutorial, and trying to access the Youtube Data API v3, but in Chrome console I get the error `Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys`. I'm not sure why I'm getting a Google Maps warning, because I registered an API key for Youtube.

Clicked Go to Credentials.

[image: Clicked Go to Credentials.]

Clicked "API Key".

[image: Clicked "API Key".]

Clicked "Browser".

[image: Clicked "Browser".]

Set name and clicked create.

[image: Set name and clicked create.]

Copied and pasted API into JS file.

[image: Copied and pasted API into JS file.]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from "react/lib/ReactDOM";
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';

import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';


const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyD9WN2t4lhIZ5Es34jwaerM98r2nSutLJs';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

      this.state = {videos: []};

    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (videos) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({videos});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" in your index.html file. Comment out that line to prevent google maps trying to load up without a key

Answer (score 1):

You must be loading the Google Maps API without specifying an API key.

Have a look in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools and see if anything's loading `/maps/api/js` - then try and track down which part of your code is pulling in the Google Maps API.